# following scenario: why all the data did not get copied into the table?

Tags: sql, insert, teradata

Main table: Line
New table: Line_2

Eventually the Line_2 will be renamed to Line, and the Line will be renamed to Line_bkup.
All the data needs to be copied from Line to Line_2.

I started the copying process from Line to Line_2 using the following command.

Insert into Line_2 sel * from database_v.Line (data is being fetched from the view here).
The database_v.Line view has the "LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS" for the Line table.

The above insert was run at 1:00 PM and ran till 4:00 PM. (say 1000 rows were there to be copied)

In the interim, an insert was run on Line at 1:30 PM which ran till 1:45 PM. (say 200 rows were inserted)

Why did the 200 rows did not get inserted in to the Line_2? Does it have something to do with the ACCESS lock which was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly right. Using an access lock takes an image of the selected table at the time the command is committed. 
If you wish to make an exact copy of the entire table, a table-level read lock will be necessary rather than row-level access lock. This can be done in the view definition.